# can android emulator be rebooted from adb shell?

Tags: android, android-emulator, reboot

i need to reboot my android emulator from adb shell

```
preetam@ubuntu:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools$ ./adb shell
# su
# mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system
# reboot
```

i tried this commands, but they didn't work. Is there any other way to reboot the emulator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reboot emulator to test ACTION\_BOOT\_COMPLETED?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241667/how-to-reboot-emulator-to-test-action-boot-completed)