# How to reboot emulator to test ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED?

Tags: android, emulation, reboot

Well, I have searched a lot. People say that I need to close the window of emulator to close it. However, I need to reboot the emulator to catch [`ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE`D](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) by my [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the following command from adb:

```
adb shell am activity/service/broadcast -a ACTION -c CATEGORY -n NAME
```

for example:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n package_name/class_name
```

Note that class name and package names need to be as defined in the Manifest.

This will generate the Intent you want , directed only to the component you want (otherwise you system will go crazy with BOOT_COMPLETED sent...)

Comment: Thanks. The code looks great. Currently I don't have time to test. But I found out that without using snapshot, the emulator is a lot faster in booting, and closing  :-)  I like it!

Comment: when I execute that from Android Studio terminal (emulator with Android 7.1.1 is running), I get the message `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=7432, uid=2000`

Answer (score 31):

Or another way (also from the command line):

```
adb shell stop
adb shell start
```

Comment: yeah i was able to verify my onReceive was called listening for BOOT_COMPLETED using this way. However, the break point I had didn't hit because the debugger became detached, but I saw my log statement in DDMS.

Comment: in Android studio terminal, I get the message `stop: must be root` whilst Android 7.1.1 emulator is running

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere I accidentally mashed `adb -e root` in my terminal and it printed `restarting adbd as root`. After that I was able to run these commands.

Answer (score 9):

First, make sure that USB Debugging is enabled from within the emulator:

click:

- the Home icon
- Menu icon
- 'Settings'
- 'Applications'
- 'Development'
- make sure that the box next to 'USB debugging' contains a check mark

from a command-line:

```
adb -e reboot
```

**EDIT:**

This definitely doesn't work... very strange. I tested it and could not make the emulator reboot. It just hangs.

Comment: Excuse me, could you tell me if you run `adb reboot` successfully? I run it for 45 mins, the process `emulator-arm` keeps using 50% of CPU. It's not responding  :-(

Answer (score 8):

To emulate a broadcast action, you can connect via *adb* to the emulator/device and open a shell:

```
adb shell
```

Then, you can broadcast the action you want to test:

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Please note that, in the latest Android versions, broadcasting the *android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED* action will actually reboot your emulator/device.

Comment: on Android emulator 7.1.1, I get the following message on Terminal: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=6832, uid=2000`

Answer (score 0):

While using `tubemate` on android tab, I was not successful in downloading video with the `error:host interupped` etc. I used the following commands:

```
adb shell stop
adb shell start
```

and the application started downloading videos.

Answer (score -3):

emulators have on/off button - just click it

Comment: When I click the power button (and hold for 2 or 3 secs), it acts as like real device: it shows me menu of Silent mode/ Airplane mode/ Power off. I click Power off, but then I can't turn it on :-( . It keeps showing "Shutting down..."

Comment: holding power button helps (current latest emulator version)

Answer (score -3):

and another way:

If you start your emulator, and select the "wipe user data" checkbox, you will also receive that notification when boot is completed.

Comment: But if I wipe data, the app that I installed will be erased  :-)

Comment: Have you tested that Wipe Use Data does in fact erase installed apps? I believe that it will wipe data (preferences, cache, etc) that have been stored by apps, but not the apps themselves...

Comment: @DavidDraughn, Sorry for late reply... But it erases all and returns original.