# How To Test BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, android-broadcastreceiver, reboot

I want to check the BROADCAST RECEIVER with Action BOOT_COMPLETED in the emulator.

This my code

```
public class AutoRunService extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Toast.makeText(UApplication.getInstance(), "Application is ready to open ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        myFunciton(context);

    }
}

public void myFunciton(Context context) {

}
```

}

```
<receiver
        android:name=".AutoRunService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I'm using windows 10 and genymotion emulator.
Is there any way to check that broadcast receiver in emulator ? How can i restart emulator to check that receiver ? is there any direct command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Go to adb tools -> goto adb shell and use following command

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p com.example.package
```

Comment: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon

Comment: try with normal emulator

Comment: What do you mean? @apk

Comment: use avd emulator n check else try on device

Answer (score 0):

Just put a debug log inside your onRecieve() callback as follows :

```
        public class AutoRunService extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
             Log.d("Boot", "completed"); // log to make sure that boot completed action is received
            }
        }
```

And to restart the emulator, refer the following answer :

[How to reboot emulator to test ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241667/how-to-reboot-emulator-to-test-action-boot-completed)